# Display PDF with Angular and Core 2.0

Tags: angular, pdf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to display a PDF, but the actual PDF should depend on where the user is clicking. This example is cut down to a minimum, so it contains no user interaction, but it's where I intend to go. To create this example I used the default project created by visual studio and changed the following two files.

home.component.ts

```
import { Compinent } from 'angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    pdfurl: string = "http://eloquentjavascript.net/Eloquent_JavaScript.pdf"; /*dummy PDF*/
}
```

home.component.html

```
<p>{{ pdfurl }}</p>

<a [attr.href]="pdfurl">PDF</a>

<h5>iframe</h5>
<iframe width="500" height="600" [attr.src]="pdfurl" type="application/pdf"></iframe>

<h5>object</h5>
<object [attr.data]="pdfurl" type="application/pdf"></object>

<h5>embed</h5>
<embed [attr.src]="pdfurl" type="application/pdf">
```

Running this shows the url and also the link is working properly, but none of the following attempts to display the PDF is working. 
Please explain me why this is not working and how it's suppost to be done instead.